# Using OpenID for both .NET/Windows and PHP/Linux/Apache web sites

Tags: php, asp.net, linux, apache, openid

**Is it possible to use `OpenID` for *both* `.NET` web sites and `PHP` websites (Apache/Linux)?**

I have a manager that wants *single sign-on for access to any/all web sites, regardless of which web server hosts a web site*.

I create `.NET` web apps and the `PHP` web sites/apps are done by another programmer.

How would I go about using `OpenID` for a `.NET` web app?

What about for the `PHP` programmer?

Answer (score 4):

For .NET: http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/

For PHP: http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenID for all sites, regardless of platform. Use this for ease of login (it's javascript):
https://www.idselector.com/

For your .NET sites, dotnetopenid works nicely. For PHP you can use the code from here:
http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/

OpenID uses the URL to identify the site - not the technology.

Answer (score 0):

use the following library:

http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid