# Share sessions between .aspx and .php on an IIS server

Tags: php, asp.net, session, iis-7

I know IIS server primarily hosts ASP.NET applications.

However, PHP applications are also hostable on IIS.

I have developed applications in both PHP and ASP.NET.

I don't want to go through the stress of rewriting the php to ASP.NET

I want to have both PHP and ASP.NET in the same application.

I know I can transfer information using querystrings, but I also want to be a ble to share session data.

How can i go about sharing session data in both .aspx and .php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not practically tested this, but I think this is what you are looking for: [How to Share Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479313)

Also refer to this question [How to share sessions between PHP and ASP.net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application)

The basic idea is that you store SESSION parameters in a database table and different apps check if those SESSION values exist.