# detect incoming url in php

Tags: php, asp.net, url

Hello to all I am here facing some situation of detecting url in asp.net as well as php.Actualy i am using php url in my asp.net page.For Example.I am using a domain like

www.smlsml.com.pk inside this domain i am using asp.net pages and in asp.net page i am calling the php url like www.phpurl.com.Problem is that i want to secure the php url while this is calling from the www.smlsml.com.pk.I mean when i call the php url from asp.net page then php url should chek while if the php url is being called from www.smlsml.com.pk then it would be open else if it opens directly or any other except www.smlsml.com.pk then it should redirect to Myasp.aspx page where i used the iframe and its src is php url so when aspx page will called it require for authentication.If anyone got understand my idea then please help me to do in php or in asp.net because i am new to php and in asp.net i dnt know how to secure a php page.Please any one help or if any one have better idea than this then please share to me.Thanks in advance

**Update**

```
$adeel = array("http://a.sml.com.pk","http://a.sml.com.pk");
if(!in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],$adeel)){
echo "Outer";
}
else{
echo "inner";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about checking the referrer of the HTTP-request, i.e. the URL where you PHP-Script was called from.

This URL is in the PHP-Enviroment-Variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

But one note though: this is a big security hole as this referrer can easily be faked or omitted. So you better pass some security token along the request that you can check against (however you can not use the same session).

Here is another question about passing a session token from ASP to PHP:

[Persist Session from ASP.NET to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199395/persist-session-from-asp-net-to-php)

---

If you want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` nevertheless, you may want to check only the domain, not the full URI. It's best to isolate the domain name then, e.g.

```
$referrerDomain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

and use that in your `in_array()` function:

```
$adeel = array("a.sml.com.pk", "b.sml.com.pk");
    if (! in_array(referrerDomain, $adeel)){
        echo "Outer";
    }
    else {
        echo "inner";
    }
```

Comment: Sir I used the above code in php page as on update but this is not doing anything will u please chek it or any modification in this

Comment: You are using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` which holds the name of the server where this script is actually running, but you need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (see my post). But keep in mind, that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` holds the full URI, so you need to cut off anything after the domain name for checking.