# Cross language session variables & cookies

Tags: php, cookies, asp-classic, session-variables

In a bid to start programming in PHP, from Classic ASP, I decided to convert a very large, old, online ASP project, piece-by-piece, until I finally completed the whole thing and learnt PHP.

I've come across a section that uses session variables and cookies quite heavily. The pages attached to this section haven't been converted yet and I can't convert them for sometime. Before I go ahead and convert this section and muck up all my users sessions/access, I'm wondering if a session variable or cookie set on my ASP page will be readable in the converted PHP pages and vice-versa?

I think requesting cookies will be okay but I'm not sure if there are any implications using sessions. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex is correct about cookies; however, sessions are more tricky. Session data is stored server-side, and different languages likely store them differently.

However, [it *is* still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application) to do; you just need to make the two apps use the same session data storage. It may be as simple as configuring both PHP and ASP to store sessions in an SQL database. But they probably don't use the same format to store session data in databases, so you may end up needing to write a [custom session storage handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) for one or the other.

Then all you need to do is make sure both apps read the session ID from the same cookie name, as this differs from language to language as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Cookies, yes they will be available.**

Sessions, I don't know how ASP handles its sessions, but I don't think PHP can handle them directly.

**What you can do within your ASP script is to create session files for PHP**

Study [how PHP handles sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) , and create session files in your session folder. However, it can be tricky to encode/serialize all those values. PHP sessions aren't serialized by the serialize() function. They have [their own handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) which may depend on your configuration.

PS: Sessions last only until the client closes the browser. I say don't worry about them and activate PHP pages when you finish cloning the script entirely. If you want to run scripts written in both languages and have them pass data in between two, use cookies instead of sessions because cookies are saved on client's machine, and readable from both platforms.

Comment: Sessions do not only last until the client closes the browser (the server has no way of knowing when the browser is closed). Session data will persist until a garbage collection system deletes it. In the case of PHP, it's based on `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess I could make a more meaningful sentence. Let me correct that with "They will keep existing on the file system till the GC destroys them, but they do expire when the client browser closes."
(Actually, it's just that the client browser usually gets a new session for the next visit, because it doesn't know about the old one unless you keep the session id as a part of the URI or save as a cookie etc.)

Comment: Well, the browser forgets about the session usually because browsers are designed to ditch cookies that don't have an expiry date/time. If you configure your session management mechanism to set an expiration date for the session ID cookie, then the session can persist beyond the browser close. Though this often isn't the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Cookies are a server/header thing (the user browser communicating with your server) and so a PHP file and a ASP file will be able to change/edit all the domain cookies (assuming they are on the same domain, of course).

Comment: it's messier, as Ilyas & Lèse say in the next comments. I'd stick to cookies