# Cross domain request with credentials

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I am developing html application which will use online API.
this application will validate user and list content related to user. API are developed using classic asp. and requested from this html  using j query ajax functions .

but while accessing data related to user which will use session variables at server it don't show any kind of data cause session variable are not maintained in this app

can we maintain session variables in this html app without having in same domain

jquery code is

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
 cache: false  ,
 xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
},
crossDomain :true
});
```

Comment: If you're asking if session variables in Classic ASP are specific to domains then the answer is yes they are

Comment: You could try setting up a `hidden` field to store your values in until the page is posted back to the main application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session variables are only available with-in the scope of the original application, and cannot be accessed from other applications or servers.

If the data in the session variable is stored elsewhere and can be retrieved from a database of some sort, adding authentication to the api to return this data is one method, but can have security concerns which should be addressed in your authentication.

Otherwise, consider persisting the session data to a session-less solution, cookies, or db-cookies, which can be scoped outside of the origin and then can be made accessible to other servers. This question/answers may be helpful for that: [share session between classic ASP and PHP over than using database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631438/share-session-between-classic-asp-and-php-over-than-using-database)