# Need Communication between ASP.NET and PHP deployed on same IIS Server

Tags: php, asp.net, memcached, iis-7.5, appfabric-cache

We have the following setup:

- Windows 2008 R2 Standard.
  -ASP.NET Web Application deployed on Microsoft IIS 7.5 Web Server.
- PHP Version 5.4.21 Non Threaded 32-bit version
  -WISP (Windows, IIS, SQL Server/Express, and PHP) stack  and an ASP.NET web application
- HTTPS ( SSL )

We will ultimately deploy an ASP.NET Web Application and a PHP Web Application on the Same IIS Server.

User will first log on to the ASP.NET Web Application, but we want the user to be able to navigate between the ASP.NET Web Application and the PHP Web Application back and forth with ease.

We were planning on using Memcached technology to share session information between the ASP.NET Web Application and the PHP Web Application.

However, does Memcache handle passing URLs between the ASP.NET Web Application and the PHP Web Application?

Also, a more general question?  Is there a better alternative approach?

Update:

Instead of using Memcache, could I use Microsoft AppFabric Caching for communication between PHP and ASP.NET?  Will Microsoft AppFabric Caching work with PHP?  If yes, how well does Microsoft AppFabric Caching work with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share sessions between PHP and ASP.net application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application)

Comment: I personally think this is the first of a long list of troubles... Althoug possible, PHP on IIS is not a solution I would choose, and mixing PHP and .NET in the same application makes very few point to me (although I can imagine it's not really a choice but something you have to deal with).

Comment: @Bartdude Correct, it something our office was forced to do.  We already have an ASP.NET application that public users access, and the PHP application will be in a mature developed state.  Please suggest how to handle the situation.

Comment: @user1338998 > cfr Eric J. 's comment . And good luck with the rest of the dev...

Comment: @Bartdude Could you please tell me if Microsoft Velocity is also an alternative to Memcached in this situation?