# Cross sub-domain single sign-on between asp.net and php

Tags: php, asp.net, single-sign-on

I have an asp.net mvc application and a php application, Both of them are hosted in IIS on the same server. They have same domain but different sub-domain, like:  a.test.com, b.test.com .

Can I use cookie to realize SSO between the two applications ? Please give me some hint, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it all you have to is specify the domain while setting cookie for example when the user provides valid username and password combination on server side you can do

```
setcookie("userId", $userId, time()+3600, "/", "test.com", 1);
```

This sets cookie `userId` with the value of userId (retrieved from database).
This cookie will be available to all subdomains to test.com

More on setting cookie http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Also setting domain specific cookie is not language specific. You can set domain specific cookies in asp.net also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: How does php application to decrypt the cookie when it was encrypted by asp.net mvc application by  FormsAuthentication.Encrypt

Comment: the above solution is application specific ie subdomain may be different but the backend language has to be the same. As for your problem this link seems to have same problem as yours check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be shared across subdomains of the same domain. When setting your cookie, you can scope it to 'test.com' which means 'any subdomain of test.com can access this cookie'.

PHP's [set cookie](http://php.net/set_cookie) function has a domain parameter that can be used for that purpose.